# Identification of Board Connector

Tags: identification, connector, automotive

I'm looking for reference or manufacturer of such THT Board connector. It comes from Automotive module.
Note the PIN-Holes are elongated:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like an JST connector

Comment: Can you measure the pin-pin distance and width of the elongation?